# Form and count the most frequented pair sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating a database for the video replay site and I have a table with users and table with viewing history. I need to find using SQL query several the most watched pairs of videos. Exemple: user 1 watched videos 12, 43, 50, 66, 78; user 2 watched 12, 43, 45, 50; user 3 watched 12, 35, 50, 66, 78; user 4 watched 33, 66, 69, 78
So the two most viewed couples are (12,50) and (66,78).
But I can't even get how to form this couples for the future counting.
So, my question is how to form all possible couples and count the quantity of views of each of them.

Comment: `group by user, movie`

Comment: @jarlh - care to elaborate? I don't see how grouping by user, movie has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self `join` is the right way to do this.  I think the simplest form of the query is:

```
select vh.*
from (select vh1.movie as movie1, vh2.movie as movie2, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from viewing_history vh1 inner join
           viewing_history vh2
           on vh1.userid = vh2.userid and vh1.movie < vh2.movie
      group by vh1.movie, vh2.movie
     ) vh
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I create a subquery to simulate input data. In your application, instead of `viewing_history` you should use your viewing history table. I don't see how the "users" table is relevant in this problem. The second subquery, which I named `movie_pairs`, is an inner join of the viewing history with itself - that's how you create the pairs. I went beyond that - with that in hand, I went on to identify the pairs that are viewed together most often.

```
with
     viewing_history ( userid, movie ) as (
       select 1, 12 from dual union all
       select 1, 43 from dual union all
       select 1, 50 from dual union all
       select 1, 66 from dual union all
       select 1, 78 from dual union all
       select 2, 12 from dual union all
       select 2, 43 from dual union all
       select 2, 45 from dual union all
       select 2, 50 from dual union all
       select 3, 12 from dual union all
       select 3, 35 from dual union all
       select 3, 50 from dual union all
       select 3, 66 from dual union all
       select 3, 78 from dual union all
       select 4, 33 from dual union all
       select 4, 66 from dual union all
       select 4, 69 from dual union all
       select 4, 78 from dual
     ),
-- end test data, query begins here (but include the keyword WITH from above)
     movie_pairs ( movie1, movie2, ct ) as (
       select     a.movie, b.movie, count(*)
         from     viewing_history a inner join viewing_history b
                       on a.userid = b.userid and a.movie < b.movie
         group by a.movie, b.movie
     )
select movie1, movie2
from   movie_pairs
where  ct = (select max(ct) from movie_pairs)
order by movie1, movie2   -- ORDER BY is optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
    MOVIE1     MOVIE2
---------- ----------
        12         50
        66         78
```